# Distance of the product of two nocommuting positive operators from normal operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

This question is inspired by [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521465/approximating-the-product-of-two-positive-elements-in-a-c-star-algebra-by-a-p/4521500#4521500). Given two noncommuting positive operators $A,B\in B(\mathcal{H}).$ Let $\mathcal{N}$ denote the subspace of all normal operators, i.e. the operators $N$ such that $NN^*=N^*N.$ Determine
$$d(AB,\mathcal{N}):=\inf\{\|AB-N\|\,:\,N\in \mathcal{N}\}$$

My contribution:
In one of the answers to [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521465/approximating-the-product-of-two-positive-elements-in-a-c-star-algebra-by-a-p/4521500#4521500) it was shown
that
$$\inf\{\|AB-N\|\,:\,N=N^*,\ N\in B(\mathcal{H})\}={1\over 2}\|AB-BA\|$$
hence
$$d(AB,\mathcal{N})\le {1\over 2}\|AB-BA\|$$
Moreover $AB$ is not normal. Indeed, since $AB\neq BA,$ the operator $AB$ is not self-adjoint.
Furthermore
we have
$$\{0\}\cup \sigma(AB)=\{0\}\cup \sigma(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})\subset [0,\infty)$$ Therefore
$$\sigma(AB)\subset [0,\infty)$$
If $AB$ was normal then $AB$ would be self-adjoint by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416162/normal-bounded-operator-in-hilbert-space-whose-spectrum-is-real-is-self-adjoin), a contradiction.

Once we know that $AB$ is not normal, the number $d(AB,\mathcal{N})$ is strictly positive as the subspace $\mathcal{N}$ is closed in $B(\mathcal{H}).$ I wonder if $$d(AB,\mathcal{N})={1\over 2}\|AB-BA\|$$ or there can be the strict inequality.

Comment: I would recommend that you begin by considering the case where $\mathcal H$ is a small, finite-dimensional space; even in this case the answer is not obvious

Comment: Thanks. I have made up this question just an hour ago. I will let the audience figure out an answer. It's a good point of yours to test  on say $2\times 2$ concrete matrices.